# Mixing Liquids of Certain Viscosity

Tags: fluid-dynamics, experimental-physics, viscosity

I need a very small amount of 2 cSt liquid for an experiment I am doing, but I only have 5 cSt oil and water which has viscosity of 1 cSt.

Is it possible to mix the two up in the right proportion and so end up with some 2 cSt liquid (say 50 ml or something like that), it just needs to be enough to fill a teacup.

Comment: Related:  ["_Viscosity models for mixtures_"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viscosity_models_for_mixtures#Classic_mixing_rules_for_liquid), Wikipedia.

Comment: See Chapter 1 of Transport Phenomena by Bird et al